# header 200 not trigger in PayFast

Tags: php, payfast

i used below code(php) even then also payFast not receiving the header 200 from notify_url
Please suggest me solution, sharing the code

public function notify()
{

```
header( 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK' );
flush();

$pfData = $_POST;

if($pfData['payment_status'] == 'COMPLETE')
{
}
```

}

payFast not receiving the header 200 from notify_url.Any solution for this why PastFast not receiving
header 200 even i added
header( 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK' );
flush();

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to log a support ticket with PayFast and have them take a look at what responses you are sending at the moment to give you a better indication of where your problem is.

Your code may be sending the 200 but after a redirect which will return a redirect response and PayFast will not receive the 200.

Ensure your code is at the first thing that executes and that it is the first code that PayFast posts to.